# Joining multiple meshes without merging

Tags: modeling, mesh

Is there a way to connect multiple meshes to one mesh without unioning, so it keeps it's geometry, aka I can still select separately each mesh later on if needed?

Comment: You mean have separated (non connecting) objects linked as a single object? You can do this (CTRL+J) to join, and then when you are in edit mode, you can select the individual "objects" by pressing L.

Comment: I knew about Ctrl-J, but not that L would allow the joined shapes to be independently selectable in Edit Mode. Thanks. I predict this feature is going to improve my modeling workflow.